# Angular2 Material md-sidenav-container causes exception in ng test

Tags: angular-material

Basic use of md-sidenav-container in a fresh ng cli project causes ng test to fail on second and subsequent tests.

**Exception**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
        at ScrollDispatcher.deregister (webpack:///~/@angular/material/core/overlay/scroll/scroll-dispatcher.js:52:0 <- src/test.ts:10756:50)
        at Scrollable.ngOnDestroy (webpack:///~/@angular/material/core/overlay/scroll/scrollable.js:28:0 <- src/test.ts:86637:22)
        at Wrapper_Scrollable.ngOnDestroy (/OverlayModule/Scrollable/wrapper.ngfactory.js:13:16)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MdSidenavContainer0.destroyInternal (/MdSidenavModule/MdSidenavContainer/component.ngfactory.js:66:24)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:203:0 <- src/test.ts:82496:14)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:606:0 <- src/test.ts:82899:38)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.destroyInternal (/DynamicTestModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:115:19)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:203:0 <- src/test.ts:82496:14)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:606:0 <- src/test.ts:82899:38)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.destroyInternal (/DynamicTestModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:33:19)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:203:0 <- src/test.ts:82496:14)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:606:0 <- src/test.ts:82899:38)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detachAndDestroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:187:0 <- src/test.ts:82480:14)
        at ComponentRef_.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/component_factory.js:147:51 <- src/test.ts:40464:70)
        at ComponentFixture.destroy (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:263:0 <- src/test.ts:21186:35)
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">Drawer content</md-sidenav>
    <div class="my-content">Main content</div>
  </md-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import {TestBed, async} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import 'hammerjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  // Same test repeated enough to generate exception
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

**package.json** (default + material 2.0.0-beta.2)

```
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HostListener} from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';
import {AuthService} from './services/auth.service';
import {ConceptService} from './services/concept.service';
import {AppService} from './services/app.service';
import {Router, NavigationStart} from '@angular/router';
import {LocationService} from './services/location.service';
import {ConfigService} from './services/config.service';
import {ToastService} from './services/toast.service';
import {ContextService} from './services/context.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sidenavOpen = true;
  appElement;
  envName = 'default';
  _serverVersion: any = '{}';
  currentRoute = '';

  menuItems = [
    {route: 'home', name: 'Dashboard', icon: 'home'}
  // some lines omitted
    , {route: 'concepts', name: 'Concepts', icon: 'toc'}

  ];


  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private conceptService: ConceptService,
              private configService: ConfigService,
              private locationService: LocationService,
              private appService: AppService,
              private contextService: ContextService,
              private toast: ToastService,
              private router: Router) {
    this.appElement = elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.container = this.appElement.querySelector('.app-content');
    // Warm caches
    Promise.all([
      this.conceptService.getAll(),
      this.configService.getAll(),
      this.locationService.getAll(),
      this.configService.serverVersion().then(ver => this._serverVersion = ver),
      this.contextService.getContext().then(ctx => this.envName = ctx.name.replace(' ', '_').toLowerCase())
    ]).catch(e => this.toast.error(e));

    // Monitor size for handling sidebar
    this.onResize(this.appElement.clientWidth);
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.onResize(this.appElement.clientWidth);
      }
    });

    // Log out on closing or or navigating away
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      this.authService.logout();
    }.bind(this);
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event.target.innerWidth'])
  onResize(w) {
    this.sidenavOpen = w > 500;
  }

  isDisabled(path: string) {
    return !this.authService.isAuthorised(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your AppComponent code?

Comment: I am seeing this also,  could be a bug that should be reported on github

Comment: This last comment drew attention to your question, Jesse. I don't know how I missed it at the time.  I have added my App.component.ts to my post. (I reverted to 2.0.0-beta.1 to avoid this problem.)

Comment: There's an Bug filed for this problem on the github repo: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3391

Comment: Thanks Chris. For the benefit of others, this bug was closed as the conclusion was that the test was wrong as it did not call fixture.detectChanges() and so did not trigger onInit(). Adding the call fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem. I solved it by making global `vars` for fixture etc.

```
  fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;


 beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports:[RouterModule,UiPageHeaderModule,UiAppHeaderModule,RouterTestingModule, MaterialModule.forRoot()],
});
TestBed.compileComponents();
 });

   it('should create the app', async(() => {
const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
expect(app).toBeTruthy();
 }));

  // Same test repeated enough to generate exception
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
   //const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent); no need of this. this is causing the issue,
   const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
   expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```